# can cyphertext ever contain actual plaintext input

Tags: cryptography, plaintext

Is it possible for any commonly used symmetric or asymmetric algorithms to allow any input plaintext  to encrypt to a cyphertext that contains the actual plaintext input? Like a pathological case where there is essentially no encryption?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and for RSA may even be considered interesting. See [this](http://projecteuler.net/problem=182) problem from Project Euler, and you can also Google "unconcealed message rsa" for more links

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible? Yes. But it's **extremely** unlikely.

No cipher algorithm (pretty much since Enigma in World War II, for which this was one of the key weaknesses that let the British and Polish cryptoraphers at Bletchley Park decrypt a large number of its transmissions) guarantees that `A` will encrypt to something other than `A`. `A->A` is just as likely as `A->B`, `A->C` or any other valid alternative. It's equally likely to produce this Stack Overflow answer, or the Declaration of Independence, as it is the original plaintext, so anything legible you see in such ciphertext cannot be taken as being "passed through", it's just random chance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on cipher mode used.
For ECB mode - not likely.
But for CBC or CTR, where cleartext is xored with encrypted IV, some byte(s) in encrypted IV can be zero, and after xoring ciphertext will contain the same byte as cleartext.

Update: after some tests (see comments) got that the byte in output would be the same as in input with probability (near to) 1/256, i.e. almost the same probability if the output was random.

Comment: No more or less likely in any encryption mode!

Comment: Hm, probability that 1 byte in encrypted IV will be zero is 1/256 for random IV. Probability that encrypted byte would be the same in ECB mode should be much less, isn't it.

Comment: Why? In a perfect algorithm, probability of any byte output from a given input is 1/256 isn't it, regardless of mode?

Comment: No, each output byte after encryption depends on other input bytes. While when you are encrypting IV, you just need zero on output. I wrote a small test case, 10000 times encrypting random input AES block and got zero times when one byte on output was the same as in input.

Comment: Just run the same experiment - 1,290 bytes where input matched output, out of a possible 320,000. That's about 1 in 256. Are you using the same key and IV in each of your trials?

Comment: Omg, got it. I generated the input only once :) You are right.

Comment: :) Glad we got there. So you agree, doesn't depend on encryption mode?

Comment: Yes, I'm agree. Without dependence on cipher mode, output byte will be the same as input with (almost) the same probability as if the output was random.